# CreateObject and Common Table Expression error

Tags: sql, vbscript, common-table-expression, adodb, createobject

I got this "Common Table Expression" Sql script and it works perfectly but applying the SQL script within my code with the server.createobject i get the following error:

*Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
Type mismatch: '[string: "WITH CTE AS (SELECT "]'*

This is my code:

```
Set objFrConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 
objFrConn.ActiveConnection = db
objFrConn.CommandText = "WITH CTE AS (SELECT...some code...) " & _
"SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1 ORDER BY Date"
objFrConn.CommandType = 1
set rsListProduct=objFrConn.execute
```

Comment: Typically CTE's start with a semicolon.  Can you throw one on the front and try?  ;WITH CTE AS.....

Comment: @dfundako No, the semicolon did not work, same error.

Comment: What about not splitting up the code and just making it one string?
objFrConn.CommandText = "WITH CTE AS (SELECT...some code...) SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1 ORDER BY Date"